# I can't post a message on Facebook Wall with my application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make an application that shares the content of my website automaticly whenever a  post is posted. So I started with Graph Api Explorer. I got an access token of application Graph Api Explorer with manage_pages and publish_actions permissions.

When I use Graph Api Explorer it posts the message as page post which is I want it to be but when I use my own test application with the same permissions and query structure it posts it as fan post. Please help me what is wrong. Here is some screenshots that will help me to tell the problem:

[image]

and the result is:

[image]

Perfectly fine! But when I try to do it with my own application,

[image]
*the settings are the same as above*

and the result is:

[image]

By the way my application isn't approved becuase I didn't submit an approval. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, application approval is not necessary. You just need to use `access_token` of your page not of your profile.

```
 $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much it worked! I'll valid the answer 9 minutes later.